# Eclipse doesn't copy context correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, deployment, tomcat6

**Eclipse Version:** (Java EE): 3.7 Indigo, 32 bit 
**Tomcat version:** 6.0 
**OS:** Windows 7 64-bit SP1

**Problem:** I have created a dynamic web-app xyz in Eclipse. After properly integrating Eclipse and Tomcat, I added xyz to the local server instance, and I edited  xyz's context entry in server.xml (in the Eclipse server project) to include a jdbc resource reference.

**`server.xml (in Eclipse. Username, pwd, ip etc. below are altered)`**

```
<Context docBase="xyz" path="/xyz" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:xyz">
      <Resource auth="Container" 
                driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
                factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
                maxActive="100"
                maxIdle="30"
                name="jdbc/xyz"
                username="123"
                password="123"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1:sid" />
</Context>
```

However, when Eclipse **publishes** this server.xml file to the hot deploy folder
(in Windows, located at .metadata ... > tmp0 > conf), Eclipse **omits** the Resource refcompletely. The deployed server.xml file looks like:

```
<Context
    docBase="C:\ws\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\xyz"
    path="/xyz"
    reloadable="true"
    source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:xyz" />
```

Why is this happening? (Is there a fix?). In other words, how do I make Eclipse deploy the server.xml file **WITH** my resource ref?

Comment: Eclipse isn't publishing it, you are publishing it using Eclipse. I can't infer from this what you actually did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should put the DataSource entries in `Context.xml` and not `Server.xml`

its not recommended to use `<Context></context>` in server.xml from version `6.0` onwards.

Update : to resolve *Sever.xml* doesnt copy

refer to this quote [Source](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/39249/)

> You don't need to edit the copy in the temp directory. It will be
>   updated from the master copy (currently in configs) the next time you
>   publish.
>
> Since you know enough about the Tomcat configuration, there's another
>   thing that will help. Under Preferences > Server, select the checkbox
>   that creates resources in the workspace. Then delete the existing
>   Tomcat server and create another one. This will create all the
>   resources inside the workspace instead of in the .metadata directory,
>   so you can edit them alongside other files in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks Mukul for the insightful answer. I added the ref entry to the Context.xml and it worked flawlessly. Wondering though, why then does the Tomcat server config allow a jdbc ref to defined in-place, with the context definition?

Comment: @refactor.me if i interpret  your question properly. I suppose you mean to ask why is it allowed to define `resources` inside server.xml  ? Please clarify

Comment: @refactor.me : `context.xml` was introduced with `Tomcat 5.x` (as far as I know), before that there was no `context.xml` , so we used the `<context></context>`. Now with the introduction of `context.xml` its advisable and suggested to use `context.xml` for configuring the context, but just to maintain backward compatibility the use of `<context></context>` has not been made obsolete.